# Extract column names and sort them in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the one below:

```
A  |  B  | C   | D   |  E  |
1  |  2  | 3.5 | 2.3 | 4.0 |
```

I want to always extract any columns C through E that are greater than 2.5 and sort them in descending order of their values.

For the above example:

```
E,C is the output
```

Comment: Can columns `A` or `B` have values greater then 2.5?

Comment: Yes they could be any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `transpose` + `sort_values`

```
v = df.T.squeeze().loc['C':'E'].sort_values(ascending=False)
v.index[v.gt(2.5)].tolist()
['E', 'C']
```

---

#### `stack` + `sort_values`

```
v = (
   df.stack()
     .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
     .loc['C':'E']
     .sort_values(ascending=False)
)
v.index[v.gt(2.5)].tolist()
['E', 'C']
```

Comment: @wwii oops, oversight on my part, fixed now.

Comment: Brilliant short answer. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to extract values for your required columns via `pd.DataFrame.columns.get_loc`. Then filter and use the `pd.Series.index`:

```
vals = df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('C'):]  # or df.loc[0, 'C':]
res = vals[vals > 2.5].sort_values(ascending=False).index

print(res)

Index(['E', 'C'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Curious, why not use `df.loc[:,'C':]`?